# Corrupted PDF when attempting to download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, download, base64

I am trying to allow my users to download a PDF from our website and I got most of it working but when I attmept to open the PDF I get an error that the document is corrupted.  Where am I going wrong?

Here's my view:

```
<% @client.signed_documents.executed.each do |doc| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="flex justify-content-between w-100 mr-0">
            <span><%= link_to (doc.external_document&.name || doc.folder_id ), download_pdf_signed_document_path(doc.id), download: true %></span>
            <span><%= doc.signed_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y") %></span>
        </div>
    </li>
<% end -%>
```

Router:

```
resources :signed_documents, only: [:index] do 
    get "download_pdf", on: :member
end
```

Module:

```
module EsignGenie
  def self.download_pdf(folder_id)
    url = "https://www.esigngenie.com/esign/api/folders/download?folderId=#{folder_id}"

    begin
      response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: url, raw_response: true, headers: {Authorization: "Bearer #{ENV['ESIGNGENIE_AUTH']}"} )
    rescue => e
      Sentry.capture_exception(e)
    end

    data = Base64.strict_encode64(File.open(response.file).read)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class SignedDocumentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorize_manager

  def download_pdf
    doc = SignedDocument.find(params[:id])
    data = EsignGenie.download_pdf(doc.folder_id)

    send_data(data, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "attachment", filename: "#{doc.external_document&.name || doc.folder_id}.pdf")
  end
end
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong or if I need to specify it's Base64 somewhere?  I just want to user to be able to download the file when they click the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify the module to return the file rather than the Base64 encoded raw data:

```
module EsignGenie
  def self.download_pdf(folder_id)
    url = "https://www.esigngenie.com/esign/api/folders/download?folderId=#{folder_id}"

    begin
      response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: url, raw_response: true, headers: {Authorization: "Bearer #{ENV['ESIGNGENIE_AUTH']}"} )
    rescue => e
      Sentry.capture_exception(e)
    end

    data = response.file
  end
end
```

I then changed the controller to call `send_file` rather than `send_data` now that it's a file rather than raw data

```
class SignedDocumentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorize_manager

  def download_pdf
    doc = SignedDocument.find(params[:id])
    data = EsignGenie.download_pdf(doc.folder_id)

    send_file(data, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "attachment", filename: "#{doc.external_document&.name || doc.folder_id}.pdf")
  end
```

After these changes, the download succeeded and the file was viewable.

Comment: Even if you where to send raw data you don't need to Base64 encode it. You just need to open the file in binmode. `File.binread(response.file)` or `File.open(response.file, 'rb')`. Base64 encoding is only neccissary if you're sending files as plaintext (for example embedded in a JSON payload).